# UITableView does not scroll when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios12

UITableView does not auto-scroll when a UITextField/UITextView becomes the first responder. It used to work just fine on iOS 9-11, but now it doesn't work anymore on iOS 12.
What should I set up or change in the `tableView` to fix the behavior?

**Reference GIF**

[image]

Comment: The question is what *have* you setup so far? We need a little more detail to be able to help.

Comment: Without code how can other helps you?

Comment: Is this not default behavior of UITableView?

Comment: No, you need handle that manually. However, there's libraries like [KeyboardLayoutConstraint.swift](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/blob/master/Spring/KeyboardLayoutConstraint.swift) that take care of keyboard events where you can setup contraints.

Comment: @Ruslan, have you set the content-inset properly when the keyboard appears? if no, why not?

Comment: hmm, probably this is default behavior not tableView but UITableViewController? What do you think about this?  https://medium.com/@how_noobs_think/uitableviewcontroller-will-automatically-adjust-content-position-relative-to-keyboard-ios-swift-8810a375ffb2

Comment: Looks like that's the case, yes. Can't confirm, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solution in the code, as you said. This part of code was blame:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```